# Weka - error on Java for SVM

Tags: java, weka, sentiment-analysis

I wrote a code for SVM on Java using eclipse, Here is my code:

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import java.util.Random;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.evaluation.*;
import weka.classifiers.functions.SMO;

public class Evaluate {

    public static void main (String args [])throws Exception{

    DataSource source = new DataSource("/Users/kdash/workspace/Weka/Negative.arff");
    Instances dataset = source.getDataSet();

    //set class index to last attribute

    dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes()-1);

    //Create Classifier

    //J48 tree = new J48();
    //tree.buildClassifier(dataset);

    SMO svm = new SMO();
    svm.buildClassifier(dataset);

    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(dataset);

    // test dataset

    DataSource source1 = new DataSource("/Users/kdash/workspace/Weka/Negative.arff");
    Instances testDataset = source1.getDataSet();

    testDataset.setClassIndex(testDataset.numAttributes() -1);
    eval.evaluateModel(svm, testDataset);

    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("Evaluation: \n", false));

    System.out.println("Correct % = " + eval.pctCorrect());
    System.out.println("Incorrect % = " + eval.pctIncorrect());

    System.out.println("AUC % = " + eval.areaUnderROC(1));
    System.out.println("Kappa % = " + eval.kappa());
    System.out.println("MAE % = " + eval.meanAbsoluteError());
    System.out.println("RMSE % = " + eval.rootMeanSquaredError());
    System.out.println("RAE % = " + eval.relativeAbsoluteError());
    System.out.println("RRSE % = " + eval.rootRelativeSquaredError());

    System.out.println("Precision % = " + eval.precision(1));
    System.out.println("Recall % = " + eval.recall(1));
    System.out.println("F-Measure % = " + eval.fMeasure(1));
    System.out.println("Error rate % = " + eval.errorRate());

    //confusion matrix
        System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString("Overall Confusion Matrix === \n"));
    }

}
```

but I get following error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException:
> ```
>
> weka.classifiers.functions.SMO: Cannot handle numeric class!
>         at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:953)
>         at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1109)
>         at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1022)
>         at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1301)
>         at weka.classifiers.functions.SMO.buildClassifier(SMO.java:1250)
>         at Evaluate.main(Evaluate.java:25)

My dataset contains three different rows
1. Polarity (-1) for all rows
2. Class - Negative
3. Word occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Example of dataset:

Occurances: 1
Class:  -1
Polarity: Negative

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the arff-file is exactly organized, but the error assumes that the last attribute (where the class index is set to) is numeric (e.g. count of word occurrences)

SVM can not be build with numeric classes. Try to set the class index right (depending on the arff-file) or modify the arff-header (if the correct class index is assigned to the wrong type (numeric).